# Submitting Facebook open graph action

Tags: facebook, submit, action, facebook-opengraph

I am trying to submit a facebook opengraph action. It is a simple "Read" "Article" action, however when I submit it for approval facebook eventually responds with this error.

"Status: Changes needed
You are trying to submit a custom action which is not permitted. Please delete this action and submit a built-in version of this action instead.
Please make changes below and resubmit for review."

I am not sure what that means, as far as I know it is not a custom action that I created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click to create a new action type, and when the text box appears, start typing "read" and then select the option that drops down. That is the built-in read action.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, it seems FB doesn't allow to add built in actions as custom for some unknown reason, may be they have some future plan with them for AI stuff. The only the thing I see in built in read is its very limited.

Answer (score 0):

try this tutorial http://onlytipsandtricks.com/facebook/how-to-publish-actions-on-timeline/

Comment: Can you give a brief summary? Lone links are bad.